# Bash script not running at startup from rc.local

Tags: bash, startup

I have written a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi" > log
exit 0
```

made it executable and its successfully running.
I edited my rc.local to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/home/katph/test.sh 

exit 0
```

rc.local is executable:

```
/$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 349 Aug  1 13:19 /etc/rc.local
```

What's working:

1.I directly put `echo "hi" > /home/katph/log` in rc.local, it works fine.Meaning rc.local runs at startup.

2.If I manually run rc.local with the script, log file is created correctly.

Any suggestion? I'm running Kubuntu14.04.

Comment: If you run `bash -x /etc/rc.local`, do you see any action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
log
```

by an absolute path

```
/home/katph/log
```

---

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi" > /home/katph/log
exit 0
```